# Как правильно реализовать прослушивания сервера на android?

Tags: android, tcp

Есть сервер и клиент, которые находятся в одной Wi-Fi сети. Они соединены  посредством TCP. Требуется создать отдельный поток для клиента, который будет постоянно слушать сервер и получать от него сообщений. Как я понимаю, этот поток нужно создавать в сервисе? Как **ПРАВИЛЬНО** это реализовать?

Возможные решения:
Android предоставляет нам следующие механизмы:

1)**AsyncTask** не смотря на то, что я видел пару примеров для реализации похожих задач, AsyncTask хорош для работы в фоне на несколько секунд, а сервер может отправить запрос через минуту.

2)Обычный **Thread**

3)Используя **Handler**

4)**ThreadPoolExecutor**?

Буду рад советам или мануалам

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Простой `Service` предоставит вам фонового слушателя событий - но происходить это будет в главном потоке. Для этой задачи вам необходим `IntentService` - это такой же сервис, только асинхронный.

Answer (score 1):

У меня такая задача реализована с помощью сервиса, в котором слушаю сервер с помощью [RxNetty](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxNetty), `rx` позволяет очень гибко работать с `TCP`.

Comment: хотелось бы конечно не использовать библиотеки с такими рядовыми задачами, но всё равно спасибо.